# Images in a listfragment

Tags: android, fragment

What would I need to do to create a ListFragment that looks like this instead of just having text inside of it:

```
----------------------------------
|       |                        |
|       |                        |
| Image |      Text              |
|       |                        |
|       |                        |    
----------------------------------
```

I don't have a problem just filling the ListFragment with text but how would I go about adding that image in there along with the text?  Anyone know of any references or examples that could help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for here: http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/05/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html.

In the end instead of:

```
ArrayList<ListDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(getActivity(), image_details));
```

I just used along with the other classes for my ListFragment:

```
ArrayList<ListDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();
setListAdapter(new ListDetailsBaseAdapter(getActivity(), image_details));
```